# Node.js middleware locals update

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to build a login and logout feature.
After clicking on log in, it will bring user to the homepage and the navbar will show the username.

After clicking log out,the navbar will no longer show the username but log in button.

**However, after logging in, it directs to the home page but navbar is not updated. I have to reload and then only the navbar changes.**

Code:
Middleware in server.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.session = req.session.user;
  return next();
});
```

Setting user session:

```
 req.session.user = userinfo;
 res.redirect("/");
```

Comment: use `next();` instead of `return next();`

Comment: @mehta-rohan - That will make no difference at all.

Comment: Are you perhaps not saving your session after modifying it?

Comment: @jfriend00 what do you mean? It's saved, but I have to reload one time to see the changes, I'm sure it's got to do with the middleware issue

Comment: Some session stores require `session.save()` after you make a change to the session for that change to persist.  Please show the entire context of the request handler where you set something into the session and do the `res.redirect("/")`.